# Android - calling a method by a specified interval

Tags: android, methods, intervals

I am new to android and I am trying to build a simple application which moves a small dot on the screen which behaves like a tennis ball. To move the dot, I have got a method which updates its x and y coordinates (let us say updateXY() ). To make the ball animate forever until the user will exit application, I have to call updateXY() method based on an interval. Any  ideas on how to implements this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `TimerTask` for this. You can create a `Timer` and schedule the `TimerTask` to repeat at a fixed rate until cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

As you try to do something in realtime ( well, kind of realtime juist enough for kind of game )  you can not rely on android OS event processing  ( and also on timer tasks ). Use standart thread with sleeping to schedule updates,  and draw on surface views / canvas.